# Making a sub-path the 'root' path of my backend services on k3s?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress, k3s

I have a `k3s` cluster with a Prometheus and Alertmanager deployment inside, and set up an `Ingress` resource for each of them. My initial setup was `prometheus.domain.com` and `alermanager.domain.com` respectively, and these worked as expected.

However, I would like to switch it to `domain.com/prometheus` and `domain.com/alertmanager` respectively, and the options I have researched aren't working.

**GOAL**
Have my Prometheus service work having `domain.com/prometheus` being the 'root' of my Prometheus pathing, hence redirecting automatically to `domain.com/prometheus/graph`, as per its default behavior, and all subpaths under Prometheus (alerts, config, admin API) follow the same behavior.

**Attempt #1**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  app: Prometheus
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /prometheus($|/)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: prometheus
              servicePort: 9090
```

SSH into the Vagrant box hosting my k3s cluster:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME         CLASS             HOSTS         ADDRESS         PORTS
prometheus   <none>            *             192.168.0.200   80

$ curl 192.168.0.200/prometheus
404 page not found

$ curl 192.168.0.200/prometheus/graph
404 page not found
```

**Attempt #2**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  app: Prometheus
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: PathPrefixStrip
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /prometheus
            backend:
              serviceName: prometheus
              servicePort: 9090
```

Same result as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start prometheus with:

```
--web.route-prefix="http://example.com/prometheus"
```

From [source code](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/4e6a94a27d64f529932ef5f552d9d776d672ec22/cmd/prometheus/main.go#L160-L162):

> web.external-url",
> "The URL under which Prometheus is externally reachable (for example, if Prometheus is served via a reverse proxy). Used for generating relative and absolute links back to Prometheus itself. If the URL has a path portion, it will be used to prefix all HTTP endpoints served by Prometheus. If omitted, relevant URL components will be derived automatically.

---

And for altermanager you need to set:

```
--alertmanager.url=http://example.com/alertmanager
```

---

**NOTE:** Don't use rewrites in ingress in this case.

Comment: The `NOTE` is what did it for me. I had the `web-route` option on my arguments already, but it seems you can have just one. Thanks, man!